# SugarCRM query parameters in custom endpoint

Tags: php, rest, api, sugarcrm

## Background

I am building a custom REST endpoint in SugarCRM that joins two modules together and returns the result.  I need to allow the user to pass in optional data in the form of query parameters.  Currently the endpoint looks like the following:

```
http://base-url.com/api/customer/{customer_id}/branch/{branch_id}/offset/{offset}
```

However this requires that I pass in a value for offset. Instead, I would like to have the endpoint look like

```
http://base-url.com/api/customer/{customer_id}/branch/{branch_id}?offset={offset}
```

I have checked on the SugarCRM developer documentation and also checked online but cannot find any definitive examples of utilizing query parameters.

## My Code

Below is my code.  This code sample matches with the first endpoint listed above.  My goal is to modify the offset parameter to be a query string instead of path variable

```
<?php

if( !defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry ) 
    die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

class LinkLeadsApi extends SugarApi
{
    public function registerApiRest()
    {
        return array(
            'LinkLeadsEndpoint' => array(
                'reqType' => 'GET',
                'noLoginRequired' => false,
                'path' => array('customer', '?', 'branch', '?', 'offset', '?'),
                'pathVars' => array('customer', 'customer_id', 'branch', 'branch_id', 'offset', 'offset_num'),
                'method' => 'GetLinkLeads',
                'shortHelp' => 'Retrieve Leads for Latham Link',
                'longHelp' => 'Retrieve Leads for Latham Link'
            )
        );
    }

    public function GetLinkLeads($api, $args)
    {
         $seed = BeanFactory::newBean('w002_ConsumerLeads');

         $q = new SugarQuery();
         $q->from($seed);
        $q->limit($args['offset_num']);

        return $q->execute();

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your querystrings are still accessible in the same PHP interface via the $_REQUEST variable, but they are also available in your $args:

```
public function GetLinkLeads($api, $args)
{
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("args: " . print_r($args, true));
    $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("request: " . print_r($_REQUEST, true));

}
```

url: {sugar}/rest/v10/customer/1/branch/2/offset/3?qs=4

sugarcrm.log

```
Wed Apr 24 12:06:27 2019 [19200][-none-][FATAL] args: Array
(
    [__sugar_url] => v10/customer/1/branch/2/offset/3
    [qs] => 4
    [customer] => customer
    [customer_id] => 1
    [branch] => branch
    [branch_id] => 2
    [offset] => offset
    [offset_num] => 3
)

Wed Apr 24 12:06:27 2019 [19200][-none-][FATAL] request: Array
(
    [__sugar_url] => v10/customer/1/branch/2/offset/3
    [qs] => 4
)
```

Comment: it's also worth noting, if you don't want to populate the keys 'customer' with the value 'customer', 'branch' with the value 'branch', etc., which serve no purpose, use a blank string as their place filler in the 'pathVars'